# updated csv file data not picked up by post call

Tags: karate

Karate v0.95

**Scenario:** I am working on automating a Post call that takes a csv. In this csv there is a field which needs to be unique for each call.

**What I am currently doing is:**

1. In the feature background, reading this csv file(a.csv) and using java class updating the invoice number field to have a unique number and saving it(a.csv - same name)
2. From scenario, reading the saved csv file(a.csv) and posting it along with the request

**Expected:**
Updated csv data with new invoice number posted

**Actual:**
Old csv data before invoice number update posted. I can see the data updated in the csv file but for reason old invoice number getting posted in the call

Wondering what am I doing wrong? Any other options to achieve the same. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

**Feature file:**

```
  Background:
    * call read("classpath:features/reusables/common/JSUtils.feature")
    * def invoiceNumber = getARandomNumberWithARange(1000000000)
    * print 'Random invoice number sent:',invoiceNumber
    * def javaclass = Java.type('javaReusables.manipulateCSV')
    * def csvInvNoUpd = new javaclass()
    * csvInvNoUpd.updateInvoiceNumber("src/test/resources/features/Invoice/requestBody/01HappyPath-200.csv", invoiceNumber)

  Scenario: Verify invoice data is ingested
    Given url url
    And path 'testpath'
    And header Authorization = "Bearer "+sometoken
    And headers csvHeaders
    And def file = './requestBody/01HappyPath-200.csv'
    And request karate.readAsString(file)
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

**Java class:**

```
package javaReusables;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class manipulateCSV {

    //Takes CSV File and invoice number as parameters
    public void updateInvoiceNumber(String csvFile, String invoiceNumber) throws IOException, CsvException, InterruptedException {
        //Reads data from CSVFile and updates it
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader((new FileReader(new File(csvFile))));
        List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
        String invoiceNo = allData.get(1)[6];
        System.out.println("Existing Invoice Number --> "+invoiceNo);
        allData.get(1)[6] = invoiceNumber;
        System.out.println("Updated Invoice Number --> "+invoiceNumber);

        //Writes updated data into CSVFile
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File(csvFile)));
        csvWriter.writeAll(allData);      
        csvWriter.close();
    }

}
```

CSV File:
[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0dII.png)

Comment: With the information given, you are sending the old csv. Without your code how would we ever know?

Comment: you are on a VERY old version of karate, which is not supported. upgrade.

Comment: @mxmissile added sample files. can you please have another look. Thanks